# Количество GPS-спутников в Android телефоне

Tags: android, gps

Есть программа в Play Market называется GPS Test, которая показывает различные параметры:

https://lh4.ggpht.com/JKZYFw1qe0FBtNrKxwr9YdRZdP3-A6udAbsMXQHLuKqyqzoCmKCgpMlos7rkTtKl9fc=h310-rw

Как узнать в своей программе количество спутников и т.д. ?

Comment: можете попробовать вот это решение
         http://stackoverflow.com/a/12639587/5292979

Answer (score 1):

У класса `GPSStatus` есть метод `getSatellites()`, возвращающий `Iterable` со списков спутников (объектов `GpsSatellite`). Пройдитесь по этому списку в цикле, вызвав для каждого спутника метод `usedInFix()`, который возвращает `true`, если спутник используется для вычисления координат, и `false` в обратном случае.

Comment: т.е. вы думаете что прокомментировав решения пройдя по ссылке в комментарии к вопросу вы дадите самостоятельный ответ?

Comment: Кто вам мешал дать ответ здесь, а не в комментариях? А мой ответ - компиляция пунктов из официальной документации, которая ни мне, ни вам не принадлежит.

Comment: @s_klepcha такие ответы здесь не возбраняются.